# ftrace: Only print output of trace_printk()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, trace, ftrace

Is it possible to dump only `trace_printk()` outputs in `trace` file? I mean filter out all functions in function tracer (or any other tracer).

Comment: As far as I remember, writting `none` into `current_tracer` file does exactly that: only `trace_printk()` output is stored. Cannot check now.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thanks. But `none` is invalid value. (`nop` is there but it's used to remove all tracers from tracing.)

Comment: I think he meant `nop` and it works.

Answer (score 5):

In general, you can switch options off inside of the options directory, `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options`.  Use `ls` to display all toggle-able options.

```
# ls
annotate     context-info     funcgraph-abstime   funcgraph-overhead  func_stack_trace  hex             overwrite        record-cmd  sym-offset       trace_printk
bin          disable_on_free  funcgraph-cpu       funcgraph-overrun   function-fork     irq-info        printk-msg-only  sleep-time  sym-userobj      userstacktrace
blk_classic  display-graph    funcgraph-duration  funcgraph-proc      function-trace    latency-format  print-parent     stacktrace  test_nop_accept  verbose
block        event-fork       funcgraph-irqs
```

Toggle options via `echo`, i.e.,

`echo -n "1" > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/trace_printk`

If you are trying to filter out any output that was not produced by `trace_printk()`, you would likely need to ensure that `trace_printk()` is the only option set.

It's always good to check out the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) when in doubt.  There's also a great lwn article that helped me out when I was first learning ftrace called [Secrets of the Ftrace function tracer](https://lwn.net/Articles/370423/), which includes some sections about filtering in general.

Comment: I try what you stated, echo -n "1" > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/trace_printk, and be sure trace_printk is the only option set. /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace still prints out the available_filter_functions names when I install the related modules.

Comment: @codexplorer I believe those are the functions that output trace_printk()s

Comment: I am tracing null_blk block module. I am sure trace_printk() is the only option set. Then I checked the output of /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace, it lists
null_del_dev, null_init, null_alloc_dev, null_add_dev and so on. But obviously, those functions don't evoke trace_printk(). Do I misunderstand something? Please clue me in.

Answer (score 1):

For some who cannot get more informations from this thread...
Actually, if you use nop as an current_tracer, you will ignore all the trace except trace_printk.

do

```
echo nop > current_tracer
```

and run your kernel module or anything else which includes your trace_printk.