# trace-cmd & ftrace: print only trace_printk output

Tags: linux, kvm, ftrace

I am recording a KVM session by trace-cmd using:

```
trace-cmd record -p nop

trace-cmd report trace.dat
```

The output of the report is something like this:

[trace-cmd report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McXHE.png)

Is it possible to remove all the extra informations (CPU#, TASK, PID, Timestamp) to print only the trace_printk string (i.e. ffffffff, ffffffff, 0, 1fffffff, ...)?

I already disabled all possible options under /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options and enabled only trace_printk (`echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/trace_printk`), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592089/ftrace-only-print-output-of-trace-printk), so my trace file looks like this:

[trace file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlHgO.png)

But still trace-cmd report prints out all those extra info.